# How to find the scroll bar width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code :

```
<div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div>

div.scroll {
    background-color: #00FFFF;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

How do I find the scroll bar width?

Sample Link : https://jsfiddle.net/zc5hrkst/

Answer (score 2):

This piece of javascript should give you the scroll bar width.

```
// Select the Element
var scroll = document.getElementById("[id of div]");

// Get the scrollbar width
var scrollbarWidth = scroll.offsetWidth - scroll.clientWidth;
console.log(scrollbarWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the web browser. Normally it should be 17px.

Answer (score 0):

You can find that by substracting `clientWidth` from `offsetWidth` for y-axis scrollbar.

```
var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');
var scrollWidth = $(scroll)[0].offsetWidth - $(scroll)[0].clientWidth
alert(scrollWidth);
```

Find updated Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zc5hrkst/4/)

To find the x-axis scrollbar's height, you can use `offsetHeight` and `clientWidth` :

```
var yScrollHeight = $(scroll)[0].offsetHeight - $(scroll)[0].clientHeight;
```

Comment: This doesnt return the width of the scrollbar but the width of the whole element.

Comment: This not return `width`, it return `height` ;) ... ok, maybe by mistake ;)

Comment: @Patel no prob., no hard feeling, smiles told everything :) it's happening